# How can one apply a mask on a numpy array which leaves the original values unchanged if the mask's value is True and sets it to zero if False?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array:

```
image = np.random.random((2, 2, 3))

[[[0.01188816 0.46263957 0.00943777]
  [0.0742566  0.8375209  0.259363  ]]

 [[0.30823133 0.17924745 0.74292469]
  [0.68490255 0.03143513 0.68233715]]]
```

and a mask:

```
[[[ True  True  True]
  [False False False]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]]]
```

desired output:

```
[[[0.01188816 0.46263957 0.00943777]
  [0          0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.        ]]]
```

So, the original array should be modified according to the mask - if the mask's value is False, the entry should be set to 0, otherwise left unchanged.

What I tried:

```
(image[unknown_array])
[0.01188816 0.46263957 0.00943777]
```

This indeed gives the right values, but without the zeros. How can I get the zeros to the right place?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Multiply *image* by *mask*.

Comment: `image *= unknown_array` or `image[~unknown_array] = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using different ways:

```
x = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)  # numbers from 1 to 6
mask = x % 2 == 0                # mask for even numbers
print(x, mask)
# (array([[1, 2, 3],
#         [4, 5, 6]]),
#  array([[False,  True, False],
#         [ True, False,  True]]))
```

[Szczesny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny) suggestion is perhaps the simplest one:

```
y = x * mask
print(y)
# array([[0, 2, 0],
#        [4, 0, 6]])
```

Filling the `y` array "by hand":

```
y = np.zeros_like(x)
y[mask] = x[mask]
print(y)
# array([[0, 2, 0],
#        [4, 0, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `np.where`:

First the array:

```
size = (2, 2, 3)
array = np.random.random(size)
array
```

Returns:

```
array([[[0.36912456, 0.83634906, 0.44863801],
        [0.22061356, 0.83691007, 0.03133273]],

       [[0.47088168, 0.7737225 , 0.59968946],
        [0.59847542, 0.30779495, 0.12244422]]])
```

Then the mask:

```
mask = np.random.choice([False, True], size=size, p=[.20, .80])
mask
```

Returns:

```
array([[[False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True]]])
```

And finally `np.where`:

```
np.where(mask, array, 0)
```

Returns:

```
array([[[0.        , 0.83634906, 0.44863801],
        [0.        , 0.83691007, 0.03133273]],

       [[0.47088168, 0.7737225 , 0.59968946],
        [0.        , 0.30779495, 0.12244422]]])
```